# Android cannot called onCreate() after onResume()

Tags: android

I'm testing the function about the date change.

case1) change date to yesterday -> open the App

```
onCreate() > onResume() ..
```

case2) change date to tomorrow -> open the App

```
onResume()
```

i want that case2 works the same as case1. what can i do?

Comment: first, finish your activity and start it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, understand the Activity Lifecycle from here
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Also, you can watch any video tutorial from youtube.

And for the scenario, you have mentioned above you have to finish the activity before coming back to the same activity to call the onCreate method else without finishing activity A going to activity B, and then coming back to activity A onResume method will be called and to call onCreate call **finish()**  before changing that activity.